# IntelliJ Call Hierarchy with multiple inheritance

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

The Call Hierarchy of IntelliJ is great, it shows all the places where a method is called.
Consider the following classes:

```
interface Parent {
    void callMe();
}
class ChildOne implements Parent {
    @Override
    public void callMe() {}
}
class ChildTwo implements Parent {
    @Override
    public void callMe() {}
}
class Run1 {
    void callee1() {
        Parent childOne = new ChildOne();
        childOne.callMe();
    }
}
```

If you open Call Hierarchy on `ChildOne#callMe()` it will show `Run1#callee1`, but this is also true if you select in `ChildTwo#callMe`, because in `Run1#callee1` we created a type of `Parent` and then assigned a `ChildOne` reference, so it makes sense that IntelliJ shows on both `ChildOne` and `Two`.

Now, is there a way to make IntelliJ a bit more 'smart' and consider just the exactly runtime evaluated caller? If selected from `ChildTwo` it shouldn't return any result, as in runtime it wouldn't be called.

I'm not sure if this would be easily feasible or not, any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Hello! Please file an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues